# Trouble with Token Output When Using Custom Image with LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification

Tags: image, deep-learning, document, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I'm a beginner in NN's and have been using the LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification model from Hugging Face's Transformers library for a project where I need to extract tabular information from receipts.

I've managed to get the model up and running, and as far as I can tell, it appears to be functioning as expected. However, I've been running into issues when using a custom image for my project, and the resulting tokens I get seem to be odd.

My suspicion is that there may be an issue with how I'm using the tokenizer. I've pasted the relevant section of my code below. Could anyone help me understand what might be going wrong here?

```
from transformers import LayoutLMv3Processor, LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification
from PIL import Image
import json 

processor = LayoutLMv3Processor.from_pretrained("microsoft/layoutlmv3-base", ocr_language="de")
processor.feature_extractor.apply_ocr = True  # Enable OCR to extract words and boxes

image_path = "20180909_1.jpg"
image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")

# Preprocess image using the LayoutLMv3Processor
inputs = processor(
    image,
    max_length=512,  # Maximum sequence length
    padding="max_length",  # Padding strategy
    truncation=True,  # Truncation strategy
    return_tensors="pt"  # Return PyTorch tensors
)

for key, value in inputs.items():
    print(f"{key}: shape={value.shape}, dtype={value.dtype}")

# Inputs contains token-level input_ids, attention_mask, bbox, and pixel_values
input_ids = inputs["input_ids"]
attention_mask = inputs["attention_mask"]
bbox = inputs["bbox"]
pixel_values = inputs["pixel_values"]

# Load custom model
custom_model_path = "./model"
model = LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(custom_model_path)

# Run inference on the preprocessed image
outputs = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, pixel_values=pixel_values)

# Get the tokenizer from the processor
tokenizer = processor.tokenizer

# Extract the logits
logits = outputs.logits

# Convert logits to labels
predicted_labels = logits.argmax(-1)
label_list = model.config.id2label
print(label_list)
tokens_labels = [(tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(input_id.item()), label_list[label.item()]) for input_id, label in zip(input_ids[0], predicted_labels[0])]
```

This is how my tokens look like:

```
<s> I-article_table.article_name
ĠP O
IZ O
ZA O
ĠE O
ĠP O
AS O
TA O
Ġ+ O
4 O
NE O
U O
: O
ĠL O
âĢ O
Ļ O
ĠO O
ster O
ia O
Ġl O
ief O
ert O
Ġ- O
Ġmit O
Ġfood O
or O
at O
+ O
ĠN O
art O
in O
- O
L O
uther O
- O
Ring O
Ġ12 O
Ġ/ O
Ġ0 O
- O
04 O
109 O
ĠLe O
ip O
zig O
ĠF O
on O
: O
Ġ0 O
341 O
/ O
355 O
665 O
- O
90 O
ĠF O
ax O
: O
Ġ0 O
341 O
/ O
355 O
665 O
~ O
- O
91 O
Ġemail O
: O
Ġle O
ip O
zig O
Â® O
lost O
eria O
. O
Ġde O
ĠB O
ew O
irt O
ung O
s O
be O
leg O
Ġ07 O
- O
Sep O
- O
18 O
/ O
21 O
: O
57 O
ĠR O
g O
N O
r O
: O
AR O
13 O
500 O
51 O
ĠSte O
u O
ern O
ummer O
: O
Ġ241 O
/ O
126 O
/ O
825 O
93 O
ĠT O
isch O
- O
N O
r O
: O
Ġ405 O
ĠStation O
: O
Ġ2 O
Ġ( O
L O
âĢ O
Ļ O
ĠO O
ster O
ia O
) O
ĠEs O
Ġbed O
ient O
e O
ĠSie O
: O
ĠAt O
ika O
Ġ1 O
x O
ĠBr O
acc O
io O
Ġdi
```

I have already done this [tutorial on layoutlmv3](https://www.butlerlabs.ai/blog-posts/tutorial-train-layoutlm-on-a-custom-dataset-with-hugging-face), and it worked.

Now i saved my custom trained model and try to run inference on a custom image, but nothing wants to work properly.

I also found this [tutorial on DocumentSequenceClassification](https://www.mlexpert.io/machine-learning/tutorials/document-classification-with-layoutlmv3), where i tried to use the custom implemented EasyOcr approach (because i thought maybe its something about how my image is read out), but according to LayoutLMv3 docs, when applying ocr to true, its already used, nevertheless, both approaches didn't help.

Really looking forward for any help, thanks!